# Synchronous Save in Parse using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Using Swift 2.1 (Xcode 7.2.) and Parse 1.12.0, I'm getting an error that PFObject.save() is unavailable in Swift.  My code is:

```
 let operation = NSBlockOperation { () -> Void in

        do {
            let success = try rating.save()
        }
        catch let er as NSError {
            error = er
        }
    }
```

In PFObject+Synchronous.h, there is this:

```
///--------------------------------------
#pragma mark - Saving Objects
///--------------------------------------

/**
 *Synchronously* saves the `PFObject`.

 @return Returns whether the save succeeded.
 */
- (BOOL)save PF_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE;

/**
 *Synchronously* saves the `PFObject` and sets an error if it occurs.

 @param error Pointer to an `NSError` that will be set if necessary.

 @return Returns whether the save succeeded.
 */
- (BOOL)save:(NSError **)error;
```

So it seems as if Xcode can't tell which function to use:  it should try to use the one that handles the error.  Is there a way of forcing this, or am I calling the function incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

Although the function not marked as unavailable to swift:

```
-(BOOL)save:(NSError **)error
```

is defined to return a bool, the Swift implementation (which throws) apparently does not, so the code compiles fine if I'm not expecting to receive a return value, i.e.:

```
 let operation = NSBlockOperation { () -> Void in

        do {
            try rating.save()
        }
        catch let er as NSError {
            error = er
        }
    }
```

I'm still now sure how I could have determined this without trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

The first overload is marked unavailable to Swift, hence it is not visible.

The second overload is made available, but as you discovered yourself, it requires a `try` since it returns a `NSError` output parameter. The `BOOL` return value in Cocoa is there to indicate whether the operation was successful or not. In Swift, this is handled by catching the `NSError` instead. This behaviour was introduced in (I think) Swift 2.0, and is documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID10).

To summarize, an Obj-C method

```
- (BOOL) doSomething:(NSError**)error {}
```

maps to the following Swift method

```
func doSomething() throws
```

Comment: I was trying to find how the objectiveC code was mapping to Swift verbiage, but couldn't for some reason.  thanks